# Online Icon generator web apps?

Tags: webapp-rec

I'm looking for online web app, which lets me to upload an image and convert it into favicon and icons in desired dimensions 16X16, 32X32

I found this [Online fav-icon creator](http://www.rw-designer.com/online_icon_maker.php)...
looking for more web apps which lets me to create icons with above mentioned dimensions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- [Dynamic Drive FavIcon Generator](http://tools.dynamicdrive.com/favicon/)
- [favicon.co.uk](http://www.favicon.co.uk/)
- [GenFavIcon](http://www.genfavicon.com/)

Comment: Great :)
thats what I'm looking for

Comment: Got the best result with in the UK option, thanks Britain :o)